# How to stop window from scrolling when arrow keys are pressed - JS

Tags: javascript, events, window, keydown

Is it possible to prevent the browser from scrolling when a user pressed arrow keys using JS? I have a timer application, and when the arrow keys are pressed, I want the timer to go back 5 seconds or front 5 seconds.

This is my keydown handler:

```
function keydownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    currentSeconds += 5;
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    currentSeconds -= 5;
  }
}
```

This works, but it also scrolls the page a little. I have tried setting the body's `max-width` to `80%`, but it still scrolls when I press the arrow keys.

```
body {
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `return false`  or `e.preventDefault()` in the keydownHandler in the case of arrow keys

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.